# jquery background color change on button click inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have buttons inside the table, inside table button is clicked want to change the background color of that button and other buttons on same color

I tried using jquery like below

```
$('#bt1').click(function() {
    $('#bt1').css('background', 'red');
});
```

but it works for one button only

```
<table id="abcd">
    <tr>
        <td><button class="cellGreen" id="bt1"><font>HOME</font></button></td>
        <td><button class="cellGreen" id="bt2"><font>PROJECT</font></button></td>
        <td><button class="cellGreen" id="bt3"><font>TEST</font></button></td>
        <td><button class="cellGreen" id="bt4"><font>Help</font></button></td>
    </tr>           
</table>

<button id="btdffd1"><font>Other Buttons</font></button>
<button id="btdffd1"><font> Buttons</font></button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to go with its class `cellGreen`

```
$('.cellGreen').click(function() {
  $('.cellGreen').css('background', '');
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need this:

Change your selector to a class `.cellGreen` and apply following script which will set other button's background to default and set red to the clicked one.

```
$('.cellGreen').click(function () {
     $(".cellGreen").css("background","");
     $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zm8QH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wws4/3/)**

For all buttons use `$('td button')` as the selector

```
$('#bt1').click(function() {
    $('button.cellGreen').css('background', 'red');
});
```

For click on all buttons, use:

```
$('button.cellGreen').click(function() {
    $('button.cellGreen').css("background","");
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
```

**Note** : Your last two buttons have duplicate Ids.

Comment: it will change background color of all the buttons, here i want to change the color of clicked button(inside the table) only